# Bashcommand error when Ingest using Airflow

Tags: python, bash, airflow, google-compute-engine, pipeline

I'm looking for solution of my error. I'm planning to ingest data to GCP using Airflow that running in my VM GCP. That Airflow was running by using docker-compose
But, the DAG was failed in download task because bashcommand error. Like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash.py", line 211, in execute
    f"Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code {result.exit_code}."
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code 1.
```

This below is my download task

```
    download_dataset_task = BashOperator(
        task_id="download_dataset_task",
        bash_command=f"curl -sSL {dataset_url} > {path_to_local_home}/{dataset_file}"
```

For the url is fine. Actually,  I was checking the bash.py file in my VM, but the directory doesnt exist.

I already try to backfilling but encountered some error. Can anyone suggest the solution to download that file. Thanks

Comment: Kindly include the line of code of dataset_url, path_to_local_home, and dataset_file variable initiation.